# Inputfield unfocus after typing 1 character

Tags: html, angularjs

I can't seem to write down a full word without being unfocused after each character I type in the inputfield. Trying to understand why that is.

AngularJS

```
var module = angular.module("myModule", []);
module.controller("myController", function($scope) {
  $scope.prop = {};
});
```

HTML

```
<div ng-app="myModule">
 <div ng-controller="myController">

    <button ng-show="!prop.dropdownType"
            ng-click="prop.dropdownType = ['']">Init</button>

    <div ng-hide="!prop.dropdownType" ng-repeat="(key, value) in prop.dropdownType">
       <input type="text" ng-model="prop.dropdownType[key]">
    </div>

    <button ng-hide="!prop.dropdownType"
            ng-click="prop.dropdownType.push('')" >Add options</button>

 </div>
</div>
```

EDIT: created a quick code where you can see what i mean. Just run the code, initialize the inputfield and try to type a word: https://jsfiddle.net/wk173q0a/

Comment: so, there is no other js validation or client side script?

Comment: Hi @Sonal Borkar , thanks for the quick reply. I'm not using anything else but the code snippet above. Have a look the jsFiddle I posted to see what I mean.

Comment: posted answer below. this is happening becoz of ng-repeat call for value updation.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to fix your code by making the following change:

```
<div ng-hide="!prop.dropdownType">
   <input ng-repeat="type in prop.dropdownType track by $index" type="text" ng-model="type">
</div>
```

The problem is that you are updating the key for the values in which you are iterating over. This is kicking off a digest cycle and you are losing focus. Also, the add button did not work because you were adding identical objects with no tracking.

Lastly, you will want to iterate over an array of objects to be able to maintain the reference in ng-model. Otherwise, all the changes will be lost once you add a new value to your array.

This is a great read on understanding the digest cycle:
https://www.thinkful.com/projects/understanding-the-digest-cycle-528/

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because you are updating the list/object that controls your `ng-repeat`.

`prop.dropdownType` may start as `['']`, but as soon as you type into your input, you are updating the `prop.dropdownType` object. AngularJS sees that you have changed the `prop.dropdownType` and it refreshes the dom with the new input. If you typed the character `A`, the `prop.dropdownType` will now have a key of `A` (and a value of null?) and the input you see is now a different object.

If you change your `ng-model` to be a separate array or some other property, this issue should go away.

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because of ng-repeat in  tag. So, in this case try below 2 methods to solve the input element focus issue.

1) Use track by $index

```
<div ng-hide="!prop.dropdownType" ng-repeat="(key, value) in prop.dropdownType track by $index">
   <input type="text" ng-model="prop.dropdownType[$index]">
</div>
```

2) Wrap your strings into objects. E.g. prop.dropdownType = [{value: 'string1'}, {value: 'string2'}, ...]:

```
<div ng-hide="!prop.dropdownType" ng-repeat="(key, value) in prop.dropdownType">
   <input type="text" ng-model="prop.dropdownType[$index].value">
</div>
```

Comment: This does lose the concept of saving it in a simple array with index being just 0,1,2,3... with the input as value. Let me see if I can make this without the Value property.